# Show wait message while iFrame loading in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iframe, page-load-time

Ok, so here's the situation. I have a main page which looks something like this:

```
<div id="frameSetMainPage">
    <div id="sidePanel">
        <iframe name="panel" runat="server" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="listContainer">
            <iframe name="list" runat="server" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `panel` iframe is loaded another aspx page in code behind (via src attribute) which looks something like this:

```
...
<asp:Table ID="LinkTable" runat="server" Font-Size="10" Width="100%" CellSpacing="4">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:HyperLink CssClass="absm_link" ID="ReqListSelect" runat="server" Target="list" NavigateUrl="ReqList.aspx" Text="DR Request List"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:HyperLink CssClass="absm_link" ID="AbsListSelect" runat="server" Target="list" NavigateUrl="AbsList.aspx" Text="Absence List"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
...
```

Now these pages are showing the data from database and it takes a long time until page gets loaded (data is loaded on Page_Load event of each of these pages). My problem is that when user clicks a link, he dosn't have any visual clue that anything is working. Just after everything is loaded, page is shown on the screen. Is there a way to show a progress gif until page with data is finaly shown?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this, I just wanted to say that I found solution. Only way how this could be done is using JavaScript, because page renders only after whole server side code is executed. So one thing that can be done is to have a hidden button in the page. Remove all heavy loading code from Page_Load and move it to Click handler of that hidden button. Now in Page_Load just register client script which will invoke button click event. Ofcourse before you call the click() method, show your gif animation. Also don't forget to hide it once the work is done. It would look like this (excerpt from Page_Load method):

```
...
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  string script =
    @"$(document).ready(function () { 
      var div = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
      div.style.display = 'block';
      var elem = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
      elem.click();
    });";
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
} 
else
{
   string script =
     @"
      var div = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
      div.style.display = 'none';
     ";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "loadDone", script, true);
}
...
```

Hope this will help someone.